# cat "input file is output file" while trying to combine multiple files into one

Tags: command-line, bash, redirection, xargs, syntax

The plan was to collect all source lines of Java into one file, recursively:

```
$ find . -name '*.java' | xargs cat >> all.java
```

But there was an error:

```
cat: ./all.java: input file is output file
```

The file `all.java` didn't exist before this command, so I thought that maybe `xargs` was trying to run `cat >> all.java file1 file2 file3 ...`

Comment: Sounds like more of a http://unix.stackexchange.com question

Comment: @user66001 It doesn't fit here? I've just tried and couldn't find a summary of this site's scope, other than it's for computer enthusiasts and power users...

Comment: @user66001 this question is 100% on topic here. It would also be welcome at [unix.se] but it is also a good fit for [su].

Comment: @terdon & Evgeni Sergeev - Just thought seeing as their is a specific sub site for Linux/Unix related questions, that this question would be better residing there. Understand that it is technically on topic in both sites. Evgeni Sergeev - There is a site scope [here](http://superuser.com/about) which will also earn one a badge for reading top to bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you can safely ignore that error. The command will run successfully and it will, correctly, ignore `all.java` itself. It is simply letting you know that it did so.

Anyway, to avoid the error you could use `tee` and `find's` exec option:

```
$ find . -name '*.java' -exec cat {} + | tee all.java
```

From `man find`:

```
   -exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
          is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
          it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
          where it is alone, as in some versions of find. 

   -exec command {} +
          This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
          the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
          each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
          tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
          matched  files.
```

So, you can use `-exec` to tell `find` to run a command on each of its results. The `{}` is replaced with the actual file/directory name found. The `+` is just the marker that tells `find` that the command ends here. I use it instead of `\;` because it will run fewer commands since it will attempt to combine them into as few runs as possible.

Or use find's `!` to exclude `all.java`:

```
$ find . -name '*.java' ! -name all.java -exec cat {} +  >> all.java
```

Or [globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option):

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ cat **/*.java > all.java
```

Comment: Googling for `cat {} +` is a bit tricky... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces doesn't explain it... I don't think I've seen this pattern before.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev they are options to `find`. See update.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that *first* the file `all.java` was created, then `find` found it and fed it to `cat`, which didn't like it because it was outputting there.

Possible solution:

```
$ find . -name '*.java' | xargs cat >> all.j
```

Or:

```
$ find . -name '*.java' | xargs cat >> ../all.java
```